# Dropdown value not persisting after saving in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

## **Question:**

I am working on a Spring MVC application where I have encountered an issue with dropdown values not persisting after saving a form. Below is a simplified version of the code along with some context:

## **Controller Code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pattern1Save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView savePattern1Data(@ModelAttribute("pattern1Structure") Pattern1Structure pattern1Structure,
            @RequestParam("hiddenFinishingWoodOutsideOther2") String hiddenFinishingWoodOutsideOther2,
            @RequestParam("hiddenFinishingWoodInsideOther2") String hiddenFinishingWoodInsideOther2,
            @RequestParam("hiddenFinishingWoodOutside") String hiddenFinishingWoodOutside,
            @RequestParam("hiddenFinishingWoodInside") String hiddenFinishingWoodInside,
            @RequestParam("hiddenrunnerFixCompOther2") String hiddenrunnerFixCompOther2,
            @RequestParam("hiddenrunnerFixComp") String hiddenrunnerFixComp,

            ModelAndView model, HttpSession httpSession) {

        isResult = false;
        // getting office id for IraishoMainStructure
        String officeId = (String) session.getAttribute(Constants.SESSION_USER_OFFICE_ID);
        // getting userId form session
        String userId = (String) httpSession.getAttribute(Constants.SESSION_USER_ID);
        int transactionDefaultId = pattern1Structure.getTransactionStructure().getIraishoMainId();
        int patternNumber = pattern1Structure.getTransactionStructure().getIraishoPatternNum();
        // pattern1Structure.setFinishingWoodOutside(hiddenFinishingWoodOutside);

        // pattern1Structure.setFinishingWoodOutside(hiddenFinishingWoodOutside);
        pattern1Structure.setFinishingWoodOutsideOther2(hiddenFinishingWoodOutsideOther2);
        pattern1Structure.setFinishingWoodInsideOther2(hiddenFinishingWoodInsideOther2);
        pattern1Structure.setFinishingWoodInside(hiddenFinishingWoodInside);
        pattern1Structure.setRunnerFixCompOther2(hiddenrunnerFixCompOther2);
        pattern1Structure.setRunnerFixComp(hiddenrunnerFixComp);

        // pattern1Structure.setFinishingWoodInsideOther2("0");
        System.out.println(pattern1Structure.getFinishingWoodOutside());
        System.out.println(hiddenFinishingWoodOutside);
        // Uncommenting the line below causes the issue
        pattern1Structure.setFinishingWoodOutside(hiddenFinishingWoodOutside);

        if (CommonLogic.isEmpty(pattern1Structure.getFinishingWoodInsideOther2())) {
            pattern1Structure.setFinishingWoodInsideOther2("0");
        }
        if (CommonLogic.isEmpty(pattern1Structure.getFinishingWoodOutsideOther2())) {
            pattern1Structure.setFinishingWoodOutsideOther2("0");
        }
        Object fieldValue = null;
        Class<Pattern1Structure> aClass = Pattern1Structure.class;
        // IraishoMainStructure transactionStructure = new IraishoMainStructure();
        // ArrayList<IraishoDetailStructure> transactionDataStructureL = new
        // ArrayList<IraishoDetailStructure>();
        // changes done by Ravi on 2022-01-04 instead of creating new object usind the
        // available
        IraishoMainStructure transactionStructure = pattern1Structure.getTransactionStructure();
        ArrayList<IraishoDetailStructure> transactionDataStructureL = new ArrayList<IraishoDetailStructure>();
        // following method call for updating the t_iraisho_data on existing details ID
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = transactionFacade.getIraishoDetailsIds(transactionDefaultId);

        try {
            // get all the fields in array form Pattern1Structure
            Field field[] = aClass.getDeclaredFields();

            for (int i = 0; i < aClass.getDeclaredFields().length; i++) {
                // set accessibility to the filed
                field[i].setAccessible(true);
                // get data of the the field
                fieldValue = field[i].get(pattern1Structure);
                IraishoDetailStructure transactionDataStructure = new IraishoDetailStructure();

                // use if block for ignore unusable fields add into the structure
                if (!field[i].getName().contains("transactionStructure")
                        && !field[i].getName().contains("serialVersionUID")
                        && !field[i].getName().contains("backbtn")) {
                    transactionDataStructure.setFieldName(field[i].getName());

                    if (fieldValue != null) {
                        transactionDataStructure.setFieldValue(fieldValue.toString());
                    } else {
                        transactionDataStructure.setFieldValue(null);
                    }
                    // this condtion will add detail id to structure for update
                    if (map != null && map.size() > 0) {
                        int detailId = map.get(field[i].getName());
                        transactionDataStructure.setIraishoDetailId(detailId);
                    }
                    transactionDataStructureL.add(transactionDataStructure);

                }
            }

        } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<IraishoDetailStructure> transactionStructureList = transactionDataStructureL;
        // set data into the transactionStructure which is necessary for insert into
        // t_iraisho_data table
        transactionStructure.setIraishoPatternNum(patternNumber);
        transactionStructure.setIraishoDetailList(transactionStructureList);
        transactionStructure.setIraishoMainId(pattern1Structure.getTransactionStructure().getIraishoMainId());
        transactionStructure.setOfficeId(Integer.parseInt(officeId));

        // here we update the user data if transactionDefaultId is > 0 it means that the
        // recored is not new it is already exist in database so we update the here
        if (transactionDefaultId > 0) {
            try {
                int transactionId = transactionStructure.getIraishoMainId();

                // delete the t_transaction_data table record before update
                // transactionDataFacade.deleteByCondition(" tbl1.iraishoMainId = " +
                // transactionId + " ");
                String addedBy = pattern1Structure.getTransactionStructure().getAddedBy();
                String addedOn = pattern1Structure.getTransactionStructure().getAddedDate();
                // here we add the added by means the use who added this record
                transactionStructure.setAddedBy(addedBy);
                transactionStructure.setUpdatedBy(addedBy);
                // here we add the added date when the record first time inserted
                transactionStructure.setAddedDate(addedOn);
                transactionStructure.setUpdatedDate(addedOn);
                // pass the structure and userId to update
                transactionFacade.update(transactionStructure, userId);
                // added the update messages key in result
                result = Constants.PATTERN1_RESULT_UPDATE;
                isResult = true;
                log.info("Pattern1 with head id=" + transactionStructure.getIraishoMainId() + " is Updated.");
            } catch (DBException | InvalidInputException | PessimisticLockException e) {
                log.error(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                // here we insert new record and get the saved record structure for again load
                // data the saved on the page so user can update it
                transactionStructure = (IraishoMainStructure) transactionFacade.insertAndGet(transactionStructure,
                        userId);
                // set save structure into pattern structure
                pattern1Structure.setTransactionStructure(transactionStructure);
                // added the save messages key in result
                result = Constants.PATTERN1_RESULT_SAVE;
                isResult = true;
                log.info("Pattern1 with head id=" + transactionStructure.getIraishoMainId() + " is Saved.");
            } catch (DBException | InvalidInputException | PessimisticLockException e) {
                log.error(e);
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

        // getting dropdowns lists
        model = getDropdownListModel();
        model.addObject("result", result);
        model.addObject("pattern1Structure", pattern1Structure);
        model.addObject("transactionStructure", transactionStructure);
        if (pattern1Structure.getBackbtn() != null) {

            if (pattern1Structure.getBackbtn().equals("back")) {
                model.addObject("backbutton", true);
            }
        }
        model.setViewName("pettern1Controller");
        model.addObject("result", result);
        return model;

    }
```

## **JSP Code:**

```
function updateOtherField() {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("finishingWoodOutside");
        var selectedOption = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex];

        // Assuming that the value attribute of the option contains //MasterStructureObj.getActualValue()
        var actualValue = selectedOption.value;
        var labelName = selectedOption.label;
        // Update the value of the text input field
        var finishingWoodOutsideOther2 = document
                .getElementById("finishingWoodOutsideOther2");
        finishingWoodOutsideOther2.value = actualValue;

        // Set the value to the hidden field for later use in the form submission
        var hiddenField = document
                .getElementById("hiddenFinishingWoodOutsideOther2");
        hiddenField.value = actualValue;

        if (labelName === "その他（○○）") {
            finishingWoodOutsideOther2.value = "";

        } else {
            finishingWoodOutsideOther2.value = actualValue;
            var hiddenFields = document
                    .getElementById("hiddenFinishingWoodOutside");

            hiddenFields.value = labelName;
        }

        console.log("hiddenFields:" + hiddenFields.value);
    }
```

```
<div class="row">

                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label><spring:message
                                code="lbl.pattern1.finishMaterialSurface" /></label>
                        <frm:select path="finishingWoodOutside" id="finishingWoodOutside"
                            onchange="disableTextField() , updateOtherField()"
                            class="form-control">
                            <frm:option value="">
                                <spring:message code="lbl.userDetails.select" />
                            </frm:option>
                            <frm:options items="${finishingWoodOutsideList}"
                                itemValue="labelValue" itemLabel="labelName" />
                        </frm:select>

                        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenFinishingWoodOutside"
                            id="hiddenFinishingWoodOutside"
                            value="${pattern1Structure.finishingWoodOutside}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>&nbsp;</label> <input type="text" class="form-control "
                            id="finishingWoodOutsideOther1" name="finishingWoodOutsideOther1"
                            value="${pattern1Structure.finishingWoodOutsideOther1}"
                            placeholder=" ">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>&nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="finishingWoodOutsideOther2"
                                id="finishingWoodOutsideOther2" oninput="handleInputs(event)"
                                onkeypress="checkNumber(this, event)" style="text-align: right;"
                                class="form-control "
                                value="${pattern1Structure.finishingWoodOutsideOther2}">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <div class="input-group-text">kg/㎡</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

## **Context:**

In the provided controller code, I have a line pattern1Structure.setFinishingWoodOutside(hiddenFinishingWoodOutside);. If this line is uncommented, the selected value in the finishingWoodOutside dropdown does not persist after saving the form.

In the JSP code, the selected value is correctly populated in the hiddenFinishingWoodOutside hidden field.

## **Issue:**

When I select a value from the finishingWoodOutside dropdown and submit the form, the selected value doesn't persist after saving. However, if I comment out the mentioned line in the controller, the selected value does persist. Unfortunately, I need this line for some specific functionality.

## **Additional Information:**

The issue seems to be related to the mentioned line in the controller.
I have checked that the hiddenFinishingWoodOutside field in the JSP is correctly populated with the selected value.

## Question:

What could be causing the selected value in the dropdown not to persist after saving when the mentioned line in the controller is uncommented? Is there a better approach to handle this scenario without compromising on functionality?